# is it possible to select specfic text of ListBox Item

Tags: c#, wpf

View declaration:

```
<ListBox x:Name="LboxItems" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Name="itemTemplate"  Text="{Binding Info}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground}"></TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code behind:

```
for (int i = 0; i < LboxItems.Items.Count; i++)
{

    var item= LboxItems.Items[i] as TestItem;

    if (monitorItem != null)
    {
        var index = item.Info.IndexOf(textToFind);
        //TODO textToFind has been found therefore highlight it 
    }
}
```

Is it possible to higlight fragment of text from ListBox in WPF?

Comment: I think I found great solution I can base on: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/103259/Highlight-Searched-Text-in-WPF-ListView

Comment: it is a good idea to post the solution here if that works for you. this will help community in general.